# How can I calculate the total number of each factor in R

Tags: r

I am dealing with a result from a web-survey.

The code is like:

```
dat <- data.frame(
group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 2),
choose = c("1,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5", "2,3,5", "4", "3,4,5", "2,5"))
```

Of course, the code above only shows the simplified model of my dataset.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    new_dat <- dat %>%  
    separate(choose, c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"),sep = ",")
    columnindex1 <- 1:6
    new_dat[, columnindex1]<-lapply(new_dat[, columnindex1], factor)
```

The output is following:

```
    group C1   C2   C3   C4   C5    
    A  1    3    4    5 <NA>    
    B  1    2    3    4    5    
    C  2    3    5 <NA> <NA>    
    A  4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    
    B  3    4    5 <NA> <NA>    
    C  2    5 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

**C1-C5 mean the answer order that participants made. For example, the No 1. participant made the choices of No 1.,3., 4., and 5.. Now I want to calculate the total number of each choice by group of participants, for example, A choose C1 for once but did not choose C2; so I have transformed all the numbers in C1 to C5 into factor**.

Finally, I hope to get a result that shows like the participants in group A chose 1 Choice No.1s, 2 Choice No.4s.

Then, could anybody please tell me how to make it through coding in R studio?
-------------------Update----------------------

Thank you for your advice and comments, I figured it out with your help.

```
df%>%
  pivot_longer(-group) %>%
  group_by(group,value) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "keep")%>%
  na.omit()%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = n)%>%
  replace_na(list('A' = 0L))
```

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry for the inconvenience. I will go to learn how to post more test-friendly question. And "A""B" "C" are same with the group in the first picture. I label them with ABC.

Comment: How are A, B, and C related to the groups in the first column? And why would you convert numeric columns to factors if you want to add them?

Comment: @camille A, B and C are just labels of the groups in the first picture. Actually, the numbers in the column are the choices in the survey. 4 means the participant chose No.4, so I converted them into factors and want to calculate the total number of each choice by group

Comment: Your first picture only shows 2 groups, and it's still unclear how you want to go from one table to the next. This is why reproducible examples are necessary

Comment: @camille Thank you for your advice. I have tried to edit with a more reproducible one.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your advice. I've tried to edit my post with a more reproducible example. I hope it can be easier to copy and test

Comment: I edit my code according to data you provide.

Comment: @Park Thank you for your help, but I think I might not say my purpose clearly. I expect the result showing people in group A choose one No.1 choice, instead of 1+4. The number in the table means No.1-5, so that's why I make them factors.

Comment: @NKevin Then do you mean that, for example,  A-C1- 1-3 times, A-C1-2- 2 times .,,,,,?

Comment: @Park Yes, you're right, although in my example A only chose C1 for once, and didn't choose C2.

Comment: @NKevin I made an another edit. Would you look up to it?

Comment: Your data and description still don't match: group A has choice 1 once, not 5 times

Comment: @camille Sorry for carelessness. I think it might be a typo and I have corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try(I changed `group` to `New_group`)

```
new_dat %>%
  melt(id.vars = 'New_group') %>%
  group_by(New_group, variable, value) %>%
  summarise( n = n()) %>%
  na.omit

   New_group variable value     n
   <fct>     <fct>    <chr> <int>
 1 A         C1       1         1
 2 A         C1       4         1
 3 A         C2       3         1
 4 A         C3       4         1
 5 A         C4       5         1
 6 B         C1       1         1
 7 B         C1       3         1
 8 B         C2       2         1
 9 B         C2       4         1
10 B         C3       3         1
11 B         C3       5         1
12 B         C4       4         1
13 B         C5       5         1
14 C         C1       2         2
15 C         C2       3         1
16 C         C2       5         1
17 C         C3       5         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

## Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Grouping by New_group
  group_by(New_Group) %>% 
  #Apply the function sum (removing NA) from columns C1 to C7
  summarise(across(.cols = C1:C7,.fns = ~sum(.,na.rm = T))) %>%
  #Format data 
  pivot_longer(cols = -New_Group,names_to = "Choice") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = New_Group,values_from = value)
```

## Result

```
  Choice `high prep` `no prep`
  <chr>        <int>     <int>
1 C1               8         2
2 C2              14         3
3 C3              18         5
4 C4              23         0
5 C5              16         0
6 C6               8         0
7 C7               0         0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code, but the error told me "Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs." I don't know why this occurred.

Comment: @NKevindid you use `across()` inside `summarise` or `mutate`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most direct way is to reshape your data. If you do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-New_Group) %>% 
  count(name, New_Group) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=New_Group, values_from=n)
```

The result is

```
   name  `high prep` `no prep`
   <chr>       <int>     <int>
 1 C1              3         1
 2 C10             3         1
 3 C2              3         1
 4 C3              3         1
 5 C4              3         1
 6 C5              3         1
 7 C6              3         1
 8 C7              3         1
 9 C8              3         1
10 C9              3         1
```